# ew@OneToOne relationship with play framework that does not use JOIN

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have 2 models with a @OneToOne relationship. Let's say a model `User` and a model `Player`. Each user is a player and each playeris a user.

Here is the code of these 2 models :

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Required
    public String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Player player;
}

@Entity
public class Player extends Model {

    @Required
    public String nickname;

    @Required
    public Gender gender;
}
```

I will always access a `Player` from a `User` and I want that when I load a User, his Player is also loaded (that's why I used `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`).

So I expect (for optimization purposes) that when I load a `User`, the query is a JOIN query that also loads the `Player`.
Something like :

```
select u, p from User u join u.player p where u.player_id = p.id
```

But when I look at the queries count and the queries debug output I can see that 2 queries are performed.
Something like:

```
select u from User u
select p from Player p where p.id = ?
```

But this is not optimized, how can I make JPA perform a join request to get my `User` and its `Player` ?

Tank you for your help!

**EDIT :** I'm using Play framework 1.2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the User class, as you noticed in your comment that the player can be null

```
public static void findByIdWithPlayer(Long id) {
    find("select distinct user from User user left join fetch user.player where user.id=?", id).first();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not work :( . When I remove "join fetch user.player" from the query it works (except it does not load the player), but with the "join fetch user.player" statement it does not work :(

Comment: Don't know what's your problem in this case but this is the right syntax to define fetch in hql (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins). You don't have to define eager fetching in the model class.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I managed to make it work by changing the request to : from User user **left** join fetch user.player where user.id = ?

Comment: I've just read more about joins in SQL and I figured out why it didn't work with just "join fetch", it's because when I register and log in for the first time, Player is not created yet, so doing an inner join with a non existing player does not work. That's why "left join fetch" works, because it loads the User even if there is no player associated to it yet

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** this answer applies only for Play 2.0 with Ebean.

It is not clear if you're using Ebean or plain JPA.

If it is Ebean, as explained in the [doc](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery_joinquery.html), you have to fetch the linked entity:

```
List<User> orders =   
    Ebean.find(User.class)  
        .fetch("player")  
        .findList();
```

Comment: I think it's plain JPA but I'm not sure, this is handled by Play Framework that should use JPA

Comment: From the doc http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaEbean, it seems that you use Ebean, since your entities are extending the `Model` class. So the provided code above should work as expected.

Comment: I'm using play framework version 1.2.5, is it Ebean too ? I can't see anything about that

Comment: Nope, sorry, I was thinking that you were using Play 2.0. Play 1.2.5 does not use Ebean, so my answer does not apply to your case. And since you're using 1.2.5, you're using JPA.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify my version. Do you have an idea with JPA? Why isn't it using JOIN in queries to optimize them?

Comment: Sorry, no clue. I would have done the same as you (FetchType.EAGER)